# Undefined path method on form for devise model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to create a custom admin form for creating new users.

Here is the form:

admins/newwebsite.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@branch) do |f| %>

  <div><%= f.label :branch %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :branch, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>

<% end %>
```

controller: controllers/admins_controller.rb

```
  def newwebsite
    @branch = Branch.new
  end

  def newwebsiteparams
    params.require(:branch).permit(:branch, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def create
    @branch = Branch.create(newwebsiteparams)
  end
```

routes:

```
  get 'admins/dashboard'
  get 'admins/newwebsite'
  post 'admins/create' => 'admins#create'
```

error:

```
undefined method `branches_path' for #<#<Class:0x57414d8>:0x57409f8>
```

Any help would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: after your form is submitted, where should control be directed?

Comment: back to the dashboard path which is admins_dashboard_path

Comment: try to redirect to admins dashboard path.. in create action

Comment: after execution of controllers/admins_controller#create, it try to loads branches/index.html.erb. It's defined in your routes.rb ?

Comment: it is not @fellons how do I make it redirect somewhere else instead

Comment: You can use redirect_to

Comment: I can't actually access the page without getting the error, so its not a creation problem, any ideas?